# how to add timeline controls to cartodb torque heatmap

Tags: carto, torque

I figured out how to add multiple torque heatmap layers to a map using  cartodb.js but I can't figure out how to add a timeline control. I know it's probably something than can be done with one line but I can't find it in the documentation and resources.

Comment: Multiple Torque layers in the same map are not officially supported, just to make it clear. Synchronizing in time different Torque layers that will be working with different ranges of time is challenging!

Comment: Interesting... so why do you allow users to add multiple torque map layers using the GUI too? I added about 5 layers in the GUI to test and it worked. So I added 9 layers to a custom map using cartodb.js and it also worked although the op-comp isn't working that good for blending the layers.

Comment: If that behaviour is possible in the CartoDB Editor is probably a bug. :-)